# CSS being ignored in IE & FFox but not Chrome

Tags: css, css-selectors, cross-browser, stylesheet

i am styling a navigation menu using the following css. I have found that it works perfectly in chrome but absolutely none of the css is beign applied in firefox or IE.

Is there something obvious that i havent done or have done here?

```
<style type="text/css">
    #ddm {
         margin: 0;
         padding: 0;
    }           
    #ddm li {
        float: left;
        list-style: none;
        font: 8pt Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    }
    #ddm li a {
        display: block;
        padding: 5px 12px;
        text-decoration: none;
        border-right: 1px solid white;
        width: 70px;
        white-space: nowrap;
        color:Red;
        border: none;
    }           
    #ddm li a:hover {
        color:White;
        background-color:#444444;
    }
    #ddm li ul {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        position: absolute;
        visibility: hidden;
    }           
    #ddm li ul li {
        float: none;
        display: inline
    }           
    #ddm li ul li a { width: auto; }            
    #ddm li ul li a:hover { }
</style> 


    <ul id="ddm">
        <li>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">test 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">test 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: CSS gets applied here just fine in Firefox/Chrome/Safari, although the sublist is hidden by default and there's no :hover action yet, so you won't see much.

Comment: Do you really need to use `pt` for font-size? And your example doesn't display anything in FF nor Chrome for me cos everything is hidden visibility which is fine i guess... So everything seems to work as Alec said.

Comment: Both of you are correct. There must be something else outside of the markup that is interfering somehow with IE and FF. Sorry for any time wasting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of you are correct. There must be something else outside of the markup that is interfering somehow with IE and FF. Sorry for any time wasting.

Answer (score -1):

The last line `display: inline` is missing a `;` at the end which is causing your problem